# how to handle the jsonp callback function using backbone

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp

I am new to Backbone, and I am confused about its jsonp calls.

I know I can do something like this:

```
var foo = Backbone.Model.extand({
    url : "/testing"          
});
var fooInstance = new foo();
fooInstance.fetch({dataType: "jsonp"});
```

what about the callback function, is it handle by jQuery? if it is..does Backbone has something like "success : function(data){console.log(data)}" ?

Comment: Yes, jQuery handles that. With backbone you can listen to the "sync" event or pass `success` along with `dataType` or you can use jQuery deferred methods like `.done` and `.fail` on the `fetch` call itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the callback function inside the fetch method.

```
fooInstance.fetch({
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function() {
    //Code  ...
   },
error:function() {
    //Code  ...
 }
});
```